# Create confidence interval plot in python

Tags: python

I want to create a graph with different variables on the x axis, and plot two confidence intervals for each variable. I have used plt.errorbar to achieve this. My problem is that I can't find a way to specify labels for the x-axis variables. Currently, the x-axis is just integers. If I change it to strings, then I am unable to plot the two confidence intervals per variable. I use "x = ... +0.2" to get them on the same plot.

```
plt.errorbar(
    x=range(10,
    y= data1,
    yerr = data1_err,
)

plt.errorbar(
    x=range(10),
    y= data2,
    yerr=data2_err,
)
plt.show()
```

Could anyone offer some hints or if its not possible with this function, to perhaps recommend another one? I need to plot vertical lines indicating confidence intervals, and they will be over both positive and negative values of y.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you want to do? Are you able to provide an example image with the expected output?

Comment: @Gabriel Something like this: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Percent-difference-and-95-confidence-intervals-from-multivariate-analysis-of-lung_fig3_263673390    I want to have two confidence intervals per variable, but I also want to have words as my x axis variables, rather than numbers

Answer (score 3):

The following code makes use of `matplotlib`'s plot markers and ticks customization:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x_ticks = ("Thing 1", "Thing 2", "Other thing", "Yet another thing")

x_1 = np.arange(1, 5)
x_2 = x_1 + 0.1

y_1 = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7, 0.1), 4)
y_2 = np.random.choice(np.arange(1, 7, 0.1), 4)

err_1 = np.random.choice(np.arange(0.5, 3, 0.1), 4)
err_2 = np.random.choice(np.arange(0.5, 3, 0.1), 4)

plt.errorbar(x=x_1, y=y_1, yerr=err_1, color="black", capsize=3,
             linestyle="None",
             marker="s", markersize=7, mfc="black", mec="black")

plt.errorbar(x=x_2, y=y_2, yerr=err_2, color="gray", capsize=3,
             linestyle="None",
             marker="s", markersize=7, mfc="gray", mec="gray")

plt.xticks(x_1, x_ticks, rotation=90)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The output image will look something like this:

[image: Error bars + custom ticks]